# How to Supplement Google Assistant's/Bards "Hey Google" with my own private questions?

Tags: bard, machine-learning, summarization, android

How can I add my own personal questions and get answers for it when I say "Hey Google" on my Android phone ?

e.g

1. (If my wife prefers purple sweet potato, How can I train Google Assistant to say purple sweet potato.
   Me : Hey Google, which sweet potato should I buy ?

Google Assistant/Bard : Get the purple sweet potato, wife approved.

2. If I have a picture of a piece of paper with my body sizes written down cursive style in Google Photos with the below details: waist - 32 inches, shoulder - 30 inches. chest - 30 inches. inseam length - 34 inches etc.
   Me : Hey Google, which size T-shirt should I buy?
   Google Assistant/Bard: Get the size M tshirt because your should is 30 inches and chest is 30 inches.
3. Connect with my Google Photos and if I have a photo taken when I was abroad in singapore.
   Me : Hey Google, when was I in Singapore ?
   Google Assistant/Bard : Most likely in 2010 since you have a picture of yourself taken there at that time. (And then automatically open that picture in google photos).
4. If I have a list of important emails in Gmail. e.g If I have a few emails with subject "kt-food-best indian food", "kt-food-best american food", "kt-productivity- how to get more done in less time".
   And these emails' body contains either a link or some important text that I have typed in them. Then how do I add them into my Google Assitant's/ Bards supplementary LLM (custom LLM that works alongside my Google Assistant/Bard LLM).